# Redirect GET to HTTPS, if necessary

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

When I try to download an URL with the HTTP protocol, I get an 400 error:

```
library(httr)
x1 <- "http://www.sonnenwende-harsewinkel.de/öko-gas/bürgerwerke/"
resp <- httr::GET(x1, httr::timeout(60))
resp[["status_code"]]
#400
```

The problem is solved when I switch to the HTTPS protocol:

```
x2 <- "https://www.sonnenwende-harsewinkel.de/öko-gas/bürgerwerke/"
resp <- httr::GET(x2, httr::timeout(60))
resp[["status_code"]]
#200
```

When I enter the HTTP address in my webbrowser, I get redirected to the HTTPS address. Is it possible to get redirected using `httr`, too?

Comment: [R Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-httr-to-detect-https-redirects/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add in an `s` to the url if you get an http 400?

```r
rGET <- function(url, ...)
{
  res <- httr::GET(url, ...)
  if(res$status_code == 400) 
    return(httr::GET(gsub("http://", "https://", url), ...))
  else
    return(res)
}
```

So you can do this

```
rGET("http://www.sonnenwende-harsewinkel.de/öko-gas/bürgerwerke/")
#> Response [https://www.sonnenwende-harsewinkel.de/öko-gas/bürgerwerke/]
#>   Date: 2020-04-30 20:59
#>   Status: 200
#>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
#>   Size: 51.7 kB
#> <!DOCTYPE html>
#> <html lang="de-DE"><head>
#>     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
#> <link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://u.jimcdn.com/" crossorigin="a...
#> <link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://assets.jimstatic.com/" crosso...
#> <link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://image.jimcdn.com" crossorigin...
#> <link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://fonts.jimstatic.com" crossori...
#> <link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://www.google-analytics.com" cro...
#> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
#> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
#> ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. However, I would like to avoid a second GET if possible or would like to do the second GET only if it is the real problem.

Comment: @KarstenW. it only does the second GET if the first one fails

Answer (score 2):

CORS Anywhere API is designed for this purpose. Prepend `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` to your url and then run the request. It might take a little bit longer as it's running through another server, but it will take care of the https issue. Here's your example using cors anywhere.

```r
library(httr)

# combine cors-anywhere url and user url
cors <- "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
url <- "http://www.sonnenwende-harsewinkel.de/oko-gas/burgerwerke/"
request <- paste0(cors, url)

# run request
response <- GET(request, add_headers("X-Requested-With" = "XmlHttpRequest"))
content(response, "text", encoding = "utf-8")
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the `add_headers` part do?

Comment: Glad to help out. `add_headers` adds a request header, which is processed by the CORS anywhere server. This is description better in this GitHub issue: [https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/39#issuecomment-387690291](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/39#issuecomment-387690291)